# Find a word jtextfield in java notepad

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, jtextcomponent, text-comparison

What condition should i put so that it highlights all the words in the JTextArea?
This code works without the while loop but it only finds and highlights the first word match.

```
String findstr = findTextField.getText().toUpperCase(); // User Input Word to find
int findstrLength = findstr.length();                   
String findtextarea = textarea.getText().toUpperCase(); // TextArea Content
Highlighter h = textarea.getHighlighter();
h.removeAllHighlights();
try
    {
        int index=0;
        while(index>=0)                             // What should I put here ??
        {
            index = findtextarea.indexOf(findstr,index);
            h.addHighlight(index,index+findstrLength, DefaultHighlighter.DefaultPainter);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    while(index>=0) {
        index = findtextarea.indexOf(findstr,index);
        if (index > 0) {
           h.addHighlight(index,index+findstrLength, DefaultHighlighter.DefaultPainter);
        }
        index++; // try adding this to allow you to look for the next index.
    }
```

Comment: Yup !! Did the trick.. Its 4 am and I was wondering for an hour... Did not realise that.. !! So dumb of me. Thank You !!!

Comment: @Sharad Tank compilable example in Oracle tutorial